# Is it correct to say "I had a race with my friends"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrase-usage

It seems that "**I had a race against my friends**" is what a dictionary often says.

My question is that:

Does it make any sense to say "**I had a race with my friends**"?

we say:

*Tom and Mary had lunch.* **(1)**

*Tom had lunch with Mary.* **(2)**

we can also say:

*Tom and Mary had a race.*

but **can we say?**

*Tom had a race with Mary.* (**the same way we say 1 & 2**)

or **we must say**

*Tom had a race against Mary.*

Comment: All of those are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would never say

> I play poker **against** my friends

It's an activity that we all enjoy together, even though it is sometimes quite competitive.

I think that, if you are talking about an informal activity, **with** is a lot better.

If you are competing in the Olympics and one of the other competitors in the event is a friend, **against** would be the correct term to use.

Answer (score 0):

> I had a race with my friends.

Is grammatically valid, and a fluent speaker might well say it.

> I had a race against my friends/

is also valid and natural. The meanings of the two sentences are essentially the same. The version with "against" emphasizes the competitive aspect a bit more, but that is the only difference.